# How to get temperature from the results of WHAM?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, temperature, simulations, software, molecular-dynamics

I ran a series of replica exchange molecular dynmaics for the different temperatures. I used WHAM to sample metastable states. From the results of WHAM, we can get probabilties ($p$) from the energy distributions of the states, allowing to get free energy by $F = -\ln p$. But I want to have temperatures for the metastable states. Is there any fancy way to get temperatures? Any suggestions and questions about the problem are welcome.

Comment: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/ might have some experts on this.

Comment: Consider to spell out acronyms.

Comment: Especially if WHAM isn't weighted histogram analysis method.

Comment: WHAM is Weighted Histogram Analysis Method.